# Android Studio Pasar parametros a dos activities

Tags: java, android-studio, interfaz-gráfica

Lo que quiero conseguir es que el **name** me lo pase a dos activities(**en el de la pantalla principal y en el menu Hamburgesa**), pero que solo se me inicie la vista de la pantalla principal.
El flujo de mi programa es esto en el create:

```
//Obtengo el nombre y la contraseña de los EditText
String name = nameEtLog.getText().toString();
String passwd = passwordEtLog.getText().toString();

//Llamo a la nueva activity, que es la pantalla principal, y le paso el parametro **name**.
Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ActivityMain.class);
i.putExtra("name", name);//Llevamos el email a la nueva activity
startActivity(i);
```

Muestro el **name en la pantalla principal**:

```
final String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
tvName.setText(name);
```

Con esto consigo que me **aparezca en la pantalla principal**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si os fijáis, tengo tres líneas pequeñas en la parte de la izquierda, que es un toolbar o menu Hamburgesa, que te muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"/>
```

Donde pone Nombre de Usuario quiero tambien mostrar el name del usuario, pero no se me ocurre como.

Comment: ¿Y el menú hamburguesa dónde está?

Comment: ya esta editado

Comment: Creo que no se entendió mí pregunta, de todas maneras adjunto mí respuesta y me dices que tal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu `onCreate` añade lo siguiente:

```
final TextView tvHamburguesa = binding.navView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nombreDelTextViewDelMenuHamburguesa); 
tvHamburguesa.setText(name);
```